# Display macbook change possible

Tags: macbook-pro

i got macbook white A1342 (i think?) with broken screen. 
and classified ad one man selling macbook's pro display.

i got a question it possible buy display from macbook pro and connect to macbook white?

Display of macbook pro is around 2009-2011 year's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently yes, you can do it. iFixit is selling a compatible screen for ~99$ and this screen is compatible for the both (Pro / Unibody).

**Screen :**

https://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/13-Inch-Unibody-LCD-Panel/IF163-024

**Fix tutorial :**

https://fr.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1342+LCD+Replacement/2988

Comment: what about all lid he selling full lid. they have same sizes for screws ? or just LCD screen possible . and thanx for reply